# relay-compile - using __generated__ relay queries of shared module

Tags: relayjs

We have a backend ruby API/graphql engine, as well as a shared UI module that are reused in different applications (both server and client side).  Each client side app customizes the use and expands upon the `ui` module.

In the following case, our `dummy` client side app (used for testing the engine) uses the `ui` library which has the majority of the UI widgets and therefore relay code (from `dummy/src/routes.js`):

```
// @flow
import React from 'react'
import Route, {makeRouteConfig} from 'found'
import AppFrame from '@alienfast/ui/App/AppFrame'
import {graphql} from 'react-relay'

export default makeRouteConfig (
  <Route
    component={AppFrame}
    query={graphql`
      query routes_DummyApp_Query {
        current_user {
          ...AppFrame_currentUser
        }
      }`
    }
  />
)
```

Error:

```
Command failed `relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./schema.json`: 
Invariant Violation: RelayApplyFragmentArgumentTransform: expected `AppFrame_currentUser` to be a fragment, got `undefined`.
    at invariant (/Users/kross/projects/af/spec/dummy/ui/node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:44:15)
    at transformFragmentSpread (/Users/kross/projects/af/spec/dummy/ui/node_modules/relay-compiler/bin/relay-compiler:4874:26)
    at /Users/kross/projects/af/spec/dummy/ui/node_modules/relay-compiler/bin/relay-compiler:4936:24
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at transformSelections (/Users/kross/projects/af/spec/dummy/ui/node_modules/relay-compiler/bin/relay-compiler:4931:15)
    at transformField (/Users/kross/projects/af/spec/dummy/ui/node_modules/relay-compiler/bin/relay-compiler:4890:23)
    at /Users/kross/projects/af/spec/dummy/ui/node_modules/relay-compiler/bin/relay-compiler:4946:24
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at transformSelections (/Users/kross/projects/af/spec/dummy/ui/node_modules/relay-compiler/bin/relay-compiler:4931:15)
    at transformNode (/Users/kross/projects/af/spec/dummy/ui/node_modules/relay-compiler/bin/relay-compiler:4854:21)
```

---

Possibly related:

- https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1790

Comment: I think you are right about the related issue. I think this is worth pushing on, since shared components between projects is a pretty common use case.